# Python inheritance class variables

Tags: python, inheritance

I've a base class.

```
class Base(object):
    CLASS_CODE = None  # This value should be set in sub-classes.

    var1 = 'E%s001' % (CLASS_CODE)
    var2 = 'E%s002' % (CLASS_CODE)


class Child(Base):
    CLASS_CODE = 'Child'
```

Now, I want to call, `Child.var1`, it should be `EChild001`, it rather gives `ENone001`.

How do I achieve the desired functionality?

Comment: Looks like your code is not using any base classes.

Comment: Oops. Missed it.